I enabled WSL and installed Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store, but why are my PC users not showing up in Ubuntu?

I installed Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store after setting up WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), but after launching Ubuntu, I encountered an issue. By default, I am logged in as the root user, and when I try to navigate the directories or list the users, it only shows system users (such as root, daemon, bin, etc.), and not the regular users from my PC, like Auwal and Smith.
I've run several commands like cat /etc/passwd, ls /home, and others, but Ubuntu under WSL doesn't recognize or display these regular users. It only lists the system users and no user directories are shown for Auwal and Smith.
How can I get Ubuntu under WSL to recognize and display my PC'’s users, such as Auwal and Smith, and how do I switch from the root user to one of these regular users?

I do not think you understand WSL.
If I understood you right you expect Windows created users to show up inside Ubuntu. Why should they? WSL installs Ubuntu as a special application on top of your Windows. It's a complete different system that runs in a container.
You can find Windows files in /mnt/ inside Ubuntu, but you won't find any users from Windows integrated into Linux. They are two completely different and separate systems that handle permissions and things very differently. Linux/Ubuntu users in WSL only exist inside WSL and are in no way connected to Windows user profiles.
